# Is there a Twitter-like app that can be installed for a corporate intranet?

Tags: webapp-rec

I think that the Twitter model of communication would work very well for disseminating information and informal discussion in the corporate world.

Is there a Twitter-like web-app that can be installed at the corporate level to provide this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can consider [StatusNet](http://status.net/)

Comment: StatusNet (formerly known as Laconica) is great.  Seconded.

Comment: and you can test it in http://identi.ca/

Answer (score 5):

Yammer which uses Yams instead of Tweets   [here](http://www.yammer.com)

Comment: I think Yammer's functionality is a sort of mix between Twitter & Facebook. But I've personally found it great in helping make company internal communication more effective across different "silos" (at least in a mid-sized company with a couple of offices).

Answer (score 3):

[Yammer](http://www.yammer.com) is basically Twitter for Business ('yams' of information) where only employees of a company are able to access the closed environment (restricted by email domain). Discussions are possible as you can view all replys below the original message. You can follow work members and set up groups for common interests/job functions. There are now also communities:

> Communities are separate Yammer networks used to
>   communicate with external  groups,
>   like customers, partners, contractors,
>   and fans of your company.

You can have a desktop application to monitor your 'yams' in a similar way to Tweetdeck works for Twitter and there are Firefox extensions.

Answer (score 0):

37 Signal has a product called backpack that is a little more than twitter but is basically what you are looking for.  I believe their Basecamp product also has it built in project specific so that each project has its own feed.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [TeamBox](http://teambox.com/) (which is actually a project collaboration tool).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use/customize the [Jaiku Engine](http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/).

But I'm not sure if it can be run outside GoogleAppEngine

Answer (score 0):

If you've got WordPress installed, you can try the [P2 theme](http://p2theme.com/). It's neat: inline comments, inline editing, real-time updates, etc.

Comment: +1 Using this now for internal keeping-each-other-up2date. Works nice. Although I would advice installing a plugin that mails notifications of new posts, at least in the beginning to get people noticing and get them active.

Answer (score 0):

My team is using [Co-op](http://www.coopapp.com/) right now for this. It's working really well, especially because it integrates with our time-tracking system, Harvest.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hipchat.com/ might be more suitable in such an environment. The guys behind it is pretty helpful and listen to their users as well.

Campfire is also an alternative.